# Apache Rewrite if file not found to another file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite my urls to another file if they do not already exist. I have an `.htaccess` file in the root of my site that looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Add slash to end of request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# API redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
RewriteRule . api/v1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ secondary\.
RewriteRule . sites/secondary [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . sites/main.php [L]
```

My intention is to serve two sites from the same folder and use the rewrites to point to the appropriate routers. The api redirect works great. However, the main and secondary redirect do not work unless I specify a route other than `example.com` (`example.com/test/` correctly rewrites).

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Add slash to end of request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# API redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^api api/v1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ secondary\.
RewriteRule ^ sites/secondary [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ sites/main.php [L]
```

Because `.` is at least equal to one character.

Comment: Thank you! I did not think about that.